# Merge Time into a DateTime to update Datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to update time info in a DateTime.

I get a string in the format "14" or "14:30" (for example), so I need to give it to Time parser to get the right hour. Then I need to update `self.start_at` which is a datetime which already has a time, but I need to update it.

```
self.start_at_hours = Time.parse(self.start_at_hours) # example 14:30:00
# NEED TO UPDATE self.start_at which is a datetime
```

I was using the `change` method on `self.start_at` but it only takes `hour` and `minutes` separated and I'm not sure what should I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about doing somethings like this?

```
time_to_merge = Time.new
date_to_merge = Date.today
merged_datetime = DateTime.new(date_to_merge.year, date_to_merge.month,
                               date_to_merge.day, time_to_merge.hour,
                               time_to_merge.min, time_to_merge.sec)
```

Comment: Yeah, it did the trick. Thanks... but I'm surprised there's no way to change info directly without have to create a new object... it's silly, isn't it? (I come from Python and I do like optimizing resources).

Comment: Hmm? Pythons DateTime is [immutable](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#available-types) too, isn't it?

Comment: @steenslag No, you can change it's attributes. To make it easier it does exist also a `datetime.timedelta` which represents the difference between two dates/hours. Please [check more about it here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Comment: @steenslag btw, I was not talking about a direct comparison (it's ok that there're differences among different PL's that's why we know different ones), but it seems silly to me that one needs to create a 3rd object instead of being able to change the one you already have.

Comment: @CodeShining I suppose it is a bit silly, lol. Because I ran into this problem early I started using only DateTime, and left the other values null, and displayed only what was needed. That way I could change my mind later and only the display would be different ;) Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

For replacing time, the `.change()` method should work, like this:

```
my_datetime = my_datetime.change(hour: my_time.hour, min: my_time.min, sec: my_time.sec)
```

For adding time, try converting to seconds and then adding them:

```
my_datetime += my_time.seconds_since_midnight.seconds
```